# <Optimised OUT> in gdb while debugging a crash

Tags: c, crash, gdb, coredump

Consider a code

```c
func ()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b;

    while (a==5)
    {
        /*** do something **/
    }
}
```

Here the variable "b" getting optimized out by the compiler makes sense. But when am debugging a crash core dump. I see that the variable because of which the code crashed is optimized out.

Can you please let me know why the variable in use is optimized out and is there a way to retrieve that variable in gdb.

Answer (score 0):

> Here the variable a getting optimized out by the compiler makes sense.

It's unclear *why* that makes sense to you. Perhaps `a` is never modified inside the body of the loop?

> let me know why the variable in use is optimized out

You haven't provided any relevant details, so it's impossible to answer this question.

> and is there a way to retrieve that variable in gdb.

Probably. You can always "recover" the value of a variable by examining disassembly and effectively reverse-engineering the optimizations that the compiler performed.

But doing this requires skill, *and* understanding the optimization, and knowing what code you are looking at (which you didn't provide).

Comment: The question is actually updated now. i was referring to variable "b". Instead of "But doing this requires skill, and understanding the optimization," It would be helpful if could provide some references. Because the question here is to find a reference and not to just know that the skill is not present.

Comment: @Darshanb Your question still doesn't have nearly enough details to meaningfully answer it.